# Basic carrier sauce/syrup for different sweet flavors?

Tags: sauce, flavor, syrup

I have an application where I would like to have a half dozen different flavors (all sweet) that are in the form of a sauce or slightly viscous liquid.

Rather then 6 recipes I am hoping to find a sauce base that I can flavor with different flavors.
i.e. Peppermint, vanilla, ginger, cinnamon, dark chocolate, etc..

Mouth feel is important.

I was considering a stock syrup but am concerned that it might be to sweet or not have a good mouth feel and would like to thicken it somehow

Answer (score 1):

Creme anglaise is probably ideal for this purpose in many desserts.  It is basically a very thin custard.

You can melt or infuse your flavor ingredients into the cream before using it to make the sauce.

Chocolate is a special case--you may want to use specific chocolate sauce recipe, as it will effect the texture of the sauce, and change its properties.  Still, chocolate creme anglaise is possible, as is a simple chocolate ganache.

Answer (score 1):

For 'most flavors' (Chocolate would be an exception as @SAJ14SAJ points out) I would recommend a '[simple syrup](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Simple-Syrup)' which you may thicken with corn starch. 
Start with a basic 2:1 (sugar:water) ratio for the syrup, add your flavoring.

- Start with distilled water, the extras in tap and most bottled waters
  will affect the chemistry.
- If it is not thick enough for you have some 1:1 cornstarch and *cold*
  water mixture standing by.
- When the water begins to boil, dial back the heat, you don't want the
  syrup to reach 230°F or it will reach the '[thread stage](http://southernfood.about.com/library/info/blcandy.htm)' and
  probably not suit your purposes.
- If you are significantly above sea-level your mileage may vary,
  experiment...

Comment: Some flavors may not diffuse well into simple syrup unless some alcohol (as from, for example, vodka) is added.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ, good point. I was 'thinking of' (and didn't say...) the flavors in the form extracts, which come with alcohol.